# Add a Google widget when Puppeteer creates a new interface page

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

Is there a way to add a Google widget when Puppeteer creates a new interface page? Specifically, the widget I'm referring to is MetaMask

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9ww6.png

I want to have the MetaMask extension loaded when I open a browser with Puppeteer so that I can test its functionality. When I click the 'Connect Wallet' button, it should connect to the MetaMask wallet and open a popup for me